# how to configure search page in Prestashop to hide/ replace Sorry for the inconvenience message in search result

Tags: search, prestashop

i am using prestashop for ecommerce website? need help in configure search result page from code part. when people search item in website and item not available then it show Sorry for the inconvenience, but i don't want it. i want to show input box or button to request that book. how to mannual configure search page in prestashop.

link below example -

https://mahiragate.com/search?controller=search&s=yadav

website : https://mahiragate.com/

design in prestashop.

i don't which file need to edit , where is message located in code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to Prestashop 1.7+ then you can comment this part in a template file, for the Classic theme is located in themes/classic/templates/errors/not-found.tpl.

Comment: themes/classic/templates/errors/not-found.tpl. i added text in this but result is same.  there no reflection in front end

Comment: <section id="content" class="page-content page-not-found">
  {block name='page_content'}

    <h4>{l s='  Line added for modifiation Sorry for the inconvenience.' d='Shop.Theme.Global'}
    <h1> Baant </h1>
    </h4>
    <p>{l s=' Line added for modifiation  Search again what you are  looking for' d='Shop.Theme.Global'}</p>

    {block name='search'}
      {hook h='displaySearch'}
    {/block}

    {block name='hook_not_found'}
      {hook h='displayNotFound'}
    {/block}

  {/block}
</section>

Comment: https://mahiragate.com/search?controller=search&s=yadav1  -  check link   - i add some txt but no reflection

Comment: my example was valid for the parent Classic theme; if you use another theme or a child theme you have to look for the similar template there.